# Dynamic data on a window that runs at the same time with buttons using python

Tags: python

I am currently working on developing a new skin for Kodi that includes buttons, windows and dynamic data such as clock and date, that will work on a touchscreen. 
I am making this project with python. So far I managed to create the screen with the buttons,windows and time/date but I have a problem when it comes to combining the button functions with the clock. 
If i set the clock to sync by the second, the buttons are unusable( the entire window is synced when the clock syncs ). If i make the buttons to work the clock show the time from the moment that kodi started. 
The script I created is based on a main class, the main display class, with all the elements as functions and objects.

The code is:

from **future** import division
import xbmcaddon, xbmc, xbmcgui, os, time,sys,multiprocessing,subprocess

addon = xbmcaddon.Addon()
addonname = addon.getAddonInfo('name')

white_color= '0xFFFFFFFF'
background_image = 'special://home//addons//script.ici.media.script//resources//img//333.jpg'
power_button = 'special://home//addons//script.ici.media.script//resources//img//icon.png'

## definim clasa Window

ACTION_PREVIOUS_MENU = 10

class MainDisplay(xbmcgui.Window):
    def **init**(self):
        # aici intra metode tip buton,text,imagine etc
        self.addControl(xbmcgui.ControlImage(0, 0, 1280, 720,background_image))

```
    self.background_image = 'special://home//addons//script.ici.media.script//resources//img//333.jpg'
    self.addControl(xbmcgui.ControlImage(0, 0, 1280, 720, background_image))

    self.strClockInfo = xbmcgui.ControlLabel(0, 15, 1280, 70,"" , font="ClockFont", textColor=white_color,alignment= 6)
    self.clock = time.strftime("  %H:%M:%S ")
    self.strClockInfo.setLabel(self.clock)
    self.addControl(self.strClockInfo)
    self.strDateInfo = xbmcgui.ControlLabel(0, 105, 1280, 0, "", font="ClockFont", textColor=white_color,alignment=6)
    self.date = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    self.strDateInfo.setLabel(self.date)
    self.addControl(self.strDateInfo)

    self.strActionInfo = xbmcgui.ControlLabel(100, 75, 400, 500, '', 'font30', '0xFFFF00')

    self.addControl(self.strActionInfo)
    # self.strActionInfo.setLabel('Push ESC to quit')

    self.button0 = xbmcgui.ControlButton(0, 50, 300, 300, 'Camera 1', alignment=6)
    self.addControl(self.button0)

    self.button1 = xbmcgui.ControlButton(980, 50, 300, 300, 'Camera 2', alignment=6)
    self.addControl(self.button1)

    self.button2 = xbmcgui.ControlButton(0, 400, 300, 300, 'Camera 3', alignment=6)
    self.addControl(self.button2)

    self.button3 = xbmcgui.ControlButton(980, 400, 300, 300, 'Camera 4', alignment=6)
    self.addControl(self.button3)

    self.button4 = (xbmcgui.ControlButton(620, 650, 35, 45, "", alignment=6))
    self.addControl(self.button4)

    self.button5 = (xbmcgui.ControlImage(610, 640, 70, 70, power_button))
    self.addControl(self.button5)

def onAction(self, action):
    if action == ACTION_PREVIOUS_MENU:
        self.close()

def onControl(self, control):
    if control == self.button0:
        self.message("Camera 1",'')

    if control == self.button1:
        self.message("Camera 2","")

    if control == self.button2:
        self.message("Camera 3","")

    if control == self.button3:
        self.message("Camera 4","")

    if control == self.button4:
        xbmc.shutdown()

def message(self, heading, message):
    dialog = xbmcgui.Dialog()
    dialog.ok(heading, message)
```

mydisplay = MainDisplay()
mydisplay.doModal()

del mydisplay

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @UnholySheep as I read in the first paragraph following "combining the button functions with the clock" is the problem, but formatting and more explicitly stating what happens and what should - might make this a better question.

Comment: yes. Sorry about that. if i make the clock to sync the buttons are not active anymore. If i make the buttons to work, the clock will display but the time is not going to be refreshed. I want to display the clock that shows live the real time and still press the buttons.